# If I move my sink, how should I route the vent?

Tags: kitchens, sink, venting

I want to relocate my kitchen sink to an inside wall from the outside wall. The vent pipe is currently in the outside wall. Can I run the vent pipe across the ceiling between the rafters ,the rafters run in the direction same direction the vent would go The walls are 11 feet apart.

Answer (score 2):

Does your jurisdiction allow Air-Admittance Valves (aka AAVs or [Studor vents](http://www.ipscorp.com/plumbing/studor))? If it does, this would eliminate the need for an external vent.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem running a vent pipe horizontally, as long as the pipe has a slope that allows it to drain back to the drainpipe by gravity (IPC 905.2). So for an 11' run, make sure the vent end of the pipe is 2 3/4" higher than the drain end (1/4" per foot).